# Draw a figure with pst-eucl

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

I want to draw the following figure:

[image: ![enter image description here]

By reading the following pst-eucl document http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/generic/pst-eucl/euclide_english.pdf, I came up with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o](0,0){O}(-2,0){A}(1,1.732){B}(2,0){C}(1,0){D}
\pstSegmentMark{A}{B}
\pstSegmentMark{A}{C}
\pstSegmentMark{O}{B}
\pstSegmentMark{D}{B}
\pstSegmentMark{C}{B}
\pstCircleOA{O}{A}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

However, when I compile in XeLaTeX, only the letter of the nodes show up. The circle and the segments don't show up at all.

Is there a way to fix my code or is there just a better way to draw that figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you didn't run `xelatex` and/or didn't view the `pdf` output:
May output with an up-to-date TL 2016.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(3,2)
    \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o](0,0){O}(-2,0){A}(1,1.732){B}(2,0){C}(1,0){D}
    \pstSegmentMark{A}{B}
    \pstSegmentMark{A}{C}
    \pstSegmentMark{O}{B}
    \pstSegmentMark{D}{B}
    \pstSegmentMark{C}{B}
    \pstCircleOA{O}{A}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that the \pstSegmentMark is not what I want and will fix it. However, I use TexMaker and ran xelatex and then view pdf and still don't see the lines nor circle even with your code. I'm downloading TeX Live 2016 to see if this will work.

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of running XeLaTeX, I ran LaTeX, dvi->ps, ps->pdf and then it worked in Tex Maker.